# How to find the average of value between intervals of date and imputing the same to a new dataset?

Tags: python

Objective:To create a new variable in the date_interval data frame and apply the result to a new dateset.

Below is the logic:

If  datev variable in the df dframe  is found in between the two dates (Date1 & date2)  in date_interval data frame then the average of the amount has to be computed basis on 'Credit segmen' and Name.The average value should be a new variable in the  date_interval data frame.
After computing the average, it needs to applied to a newdataset (df_new) and populate the average basis on the date

Below is the sample data for reference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Credit Segmen': ['A','B','A','B','C'],
                   'Name': ['red','white','blue',"red","white"],"amount":[100,345,467,345,345],
                   'datev':['4/2/2017','7/28/2017','6/1/2018','4/28/2019','8/1/2019']})

date_interval = pd.DataFrame({'Credit Segmen': ['A','A','A'],
                   'Name': ['red','red','red'],
                    "Date1":['3/1/2017','10/1/2017','3/1/2018'],
                   'date2':['9/30/2017','2/28/2018','9/30/2018']})

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Credit Segmen': ['A','B','A','B','C'],
                   'Name': ['red','white','blue',"red","white"],
                   'datev':['4/2/2017','7/28/2017','6/1/2018','4/28/2019','8/1/2019']})
```

Comment: What  have you tried so far?

Comment: date_interval['new_avg']=if(df['Credit Segmen']==date_interval['Credit Segmen']&
                           df['Name']==date_interval['Name']&
                           df['datev']>=date_interval['Date1'] &
                           df['datev']<date_interval['date2']):
                           return mean(amount)

Comment: it is giving me an error

Comment: Can you add the code and error to the question, please?